# thymeleaf renders additional <html> tags in source code

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have an index.html and a fragment.html.
When using th: replace and th:include it inserts the whole fragment template in the source code, including  and  tags. Why is this happening? I want to include "hello world" only.

`index.html`

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div th:replace="fragment.html">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

`fragment.html`

```
<html>
<body>
<div th:fragment="fragment">
<p> hello world </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`output`
right click on website -> view page source on chrome

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<html>
<body>
<p> hello world </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your `fragment.html` like following

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p th:fragment="myFragment"> hello world </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in your `index.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div th:replace="fragment :: myFragment">
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Like this you wil reffer to specific part of your template, not whole of it

Comment: if i put a class on <div class="style" th:fragment="myFragment">, but when rendering the classname is gone, leaving only <div> in source code. How do i maintain class="style"?